# displaying sys properties using servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working with `servlets` as a newbie i have been trying to get desktop application and trying to see how they could come out when i use servlets,with the `system.getproperty` method if i hit my submit button i'm getting a blank message.

this is my jsp code.

```
<form action="checkservlet" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/><br/>
</form>
```

this is my servlet code

```
package com.check.pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class checkservlet
 */
@WebServlet("/checkservlet")
public class checkservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public checkservlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        Mulizwa Mcheck = new Mulizwa();
    }

}
```

this is my class code

```
package com.check.pack;
import java.util.*;

public class Mulizwa {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Properties prop = System.getProperties();
            Set<Object> keySet = prop.keySet();
            for(Object obj : keySet){
                System.out.println("System Property: {"+obj.toString()+","+System.getProperty(obj.toString())+"}");
            }
        }
}
```

i'm  no expert but i'm here to learn,what i'm expecting from the code above if i hit the submit button i need to see the response in the browser about the system properties like os name java version etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to write a function in your Mulizwa class that might return a String of your system properties instead of its main method that prints the properties on Standard out, some thing like this

```
 public String getPropertyString (){
            Properties prop = System.getProperties();

StringBuilder propertyString = new StringBuilder();
            Set<Object> keySet = prop.keySet();
            for(Object obj : keySet){
                propertyString.append("System Property: {"+obj.toString()+","+System.getProperty(obj.toString())+"}");
            }

return propertyString.toString();
}
```

Then in your servlet's doPost method,

```
PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        Mulizwa mCheck = new Mulizwa();
write.write(mCheck.getPropertyString());
```

Comment: im geting this response Served at: /check

Comment: where do you get this response can you be more specific

Comment: as the output when i click the submit button

Comment: since that is whats return in your doGet(), chabge your jsp to call post method <form action="checkservlet" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this code in `main`,keep it in a method in `Mcheck` class like this

```
public void writeSystemPropertiesInResponse(HttpServletResponse response)) {
            Properties prop = System.getProperties();
            Set<Object> keySet = prop.keySet();
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

            for(Object obj : keySet){
                writer.write("System Property: {"+obj.toString()+","+System.getProperty(obj.toString())+"}");
            }
        }
```

And call this method in your servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        //PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();no need of this
        Mulizwa Mcheck = new Mulizwa();
        Mcheck.writeSystemPropertiesInResponse(resonse);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't wanna pass response as argument,you can use `StringBuilder` to build a string and write using `PrintWriter` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
package com.check.pack;
import java.util.*;

public class Mulizwa {

     public String getDetails(){
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("System", Locale.getDefault());
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(" ");
        Enumeration<String> en = rb.getKeys();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) en.nextElement();
            String value = rb.getString(key);
            str.append(key+":"+value +"\n");
        }
      return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

and in servelet class change doPost like the following

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(new Mulizwa().getDetails());
```